# Help me understand TradingView watchlist data

Tags: financial-literacy, foreign-exchange

I'm trying to figure out what is the meaning of the percentage value (comparing to 24-hours before?) and the small last digit?

[image: TradingView Watchlist Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percent change refers to the current price versus the price 24 hours ago.

For the first one (USDTRY), the quote is 5.7082 and is up 0.1639 or 2.96%.  Because they are rounding the percent gain to 2 decimals, there's a small error introduced.  The actual gain is 2.9562%.

To determine yesterday's price:

5.7082 / (1+.029562) = 5.5443

Today's gain is 5.7082 - 5.5443 or 0.1639 (up 2.9562 %) or 2.96% when rounded.

I don't know what the small last digit notation represents.

Comment: I've found the meaning of the small last digit notation. It's calld pippet. 1/10th of a pip. https://www.babypips.com/learn/forex/pips-and-pipettes

Answer (score 0):

The percentage refers to the difference between previous day close and current day close.
It’s based on 1D timeframe not 24h

Comment: That would be true if this weren't the FX market which is a continuous market an only opens and closes once a week. I made the same mistake at first glance at the question BTW.